# Styling multiple data-tooltips

Tags: html, css

I have multiple tooltips on my website which I created using data-tooltip. The problem is that it's an attribute so I can't just apply a class in front of it and use it. So what I want is for instance different width for one tooltip or different color etc.

This is an example in the css for the "data-tooltip"

```
 [data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide some additional html?

It's possible to use a class:

```
.my-class-1[data-tooltip] {
    width: 100px;
}

.my-class-2[data-tooltip] {
    width: 200px;
}

<div class="my-class-1" data-tooltip="true">...</div>
<div class="my-class-2" data-tooltip="true">...</div>
```

or you could also use another data-attribute:

```
[data-tooltip][data-tooltip-small] {
    width: 100px;
}

[data-tooltip][data-tooltip-big] {
    width: 200px;
}

<div data-tooltip="true" data-tooltip-small="true">...</div>
<div data-tooltip="true" data-tooltip-big="true">...</div>
```